# Issue compiling with dependency injection

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

Error with Kotlin conversion from java, this project is testing Github Api and displaying data in recyclerview.I get the a compile error which i cannot workout for `Dagger2`, it worked in `Java` but when converting to `Kotlin` i get a compile error at runtime.
It seems to be with injecting an api method into the view model 
i have tried following the error then cleaning and rebuilding the app
I have also tried invalidating caches and restarting but seems there is an error with the conversion into Kotlin from Java. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my class:

```
class RepoRepository {


private lateinit var repoService: GithubRepos

@Inject
fun RepoRepository(repoService: GithubRepos) {
    this.repoService = repoService
}

fun getRepositories(): Single<List<Repo>> {
    return repoService.getRepos()
}

fun getSingleRepo(owner: String, name: String): Single<Repo> {
    return repoService.getSingleRepo(owner, name)
 }
}
```

My component class:

```
 @Singleton
 @Component(modules = arrayOf(NetworkModule::class))
 interface AppComponent {

/**
 * inject required dependencies into MainActivityListViewModel
 */

fun inject(mainActivityListViewModel: MainActivityListViewModel)


@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    fun build(): AppComponent
    fun networkModule(networkModule: NetworkModule): Builder
 }
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
class MainActivityListViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

private lateinit var repoRepository: RepoRepository
private var disposable: CompositeDisposable? = null

private val repos = MutableLiveData<List<Repo>>()
private val repoLoadError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
private val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()



@Inject
fun ListViewModel(repoRepository: RepoRepository) {
    this.repoRepository = repoRepository
    disposable = CompositeDisposable()
    fetchRepos()
}

fun getRepos(): LiveData<List<Repo>> {
    return repos
}

fun getError(): LiveData<Boolean> {
    return repoLoadError
}

fun getLoading(): LiveData<Boolean> {
    return loading
}

private fun fetchRepos() {
    loading.value = true
    disposable?.add(repoRepository.getRepositories()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : 
DisposableSingleObserver<List<Repo>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(value: List<Repo>) {
                    repoLoadError.value = false
                    repos.value = value
                    loading.value = false
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    repoLoadError.value = true
                    loading.value = false
                }
            }))
   }

   override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    if (disposable != null) {
        disposable!!.clear()
        disposable = null
    }
 }
}
```

**this is error i am getting:**

> [Dagger/MissingBinding]     repos.network.RepoRepository cannot be
>   provided     without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated
>   method.     This type supports members injection but cannot be
>   implicitly     provided.
>       public abstract repos.network.RepoRepository 
>       repoRepository();
>                                                                    ^
>         repos.network.RepoRepository is provided at
>             components.AppComponent.repoRepository()    e: repos/di/components/AppComponent.java:19: error:
>   [Dagger/MissingBinding] repos.network.RepoRepository    cannot be
>   provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-    annotated
>   method. This type supports members injection but cannot be
>   implicitly provided.
>                            ^
>         repos.network.RepoRepository is injected at
>             repos.viewmodels.MainActivityListViewModel.ListViewModel(repoRepository)
>         repos.viewmodels.MainActivityListViewModel is injected at
>             repos.di.components.AppComponent.inject(repos.viewmodels.MainActivityListViewModel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error clearly says:

> [Dagger/MissingBinding] repos.network.RepoRepository cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

You didn't define constructor for your RepoRepository class.

It should look something like this:

```
class RepoRepository @Inject constructor(private val repoService: GithubRepos) {//the rest of your code here}
```

This goes for your viewmodel class as well.
If you are using android ViewModel architecture component i suggest you read this [article](https://proandroiddev.com/modern-android-development-with-kotlin-part-4-4ac18e9868cb) which explains how to use it with Dagger2.

Hope this helps.